# Calculating a running sum with reset in Excel

Tags: excel

[image: Sample Data]

I have a need to calculate a running sum of column D's count data in column E. However, I only want to calculate the running sum for the appropriate categories in columns B and C. In other words, there are four combinations of categories and I need a running sum for each. The easiest way is to do what I currently have in column F (cell F3=SUM($D$2:D3)) and drag it down through F11 and manually restart it at F12. I can't do this in my full dataset though because there are about 20k rows of data. So, I'm trying to make column E dynamically calculate what's in column F. I started with =SUMIFS() and can return the final sum for each combination of the two categories, but it's not a running sum, created dynamically, that resets with the new day count in column A.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 2):

**Initial Response**
If I understand the problem correctly, the solution is actually very simple.
This formula goes to E2 (and then copy down):

```
=IF(B1&C1<>B2&C2,D2,SUM(E1,D2))
```

In each case (including the first) of a change of either Cat A or Cat B, it takes the count value at that row (i.e. the new starting balance). Thereafter, it does a running balance addition (balance from row above + count at this row), until the next change of Cat A or Cat B is encountered.

**Catering for a wider range of Categories**:
The above assumes: Cat A and Cat B are only ever 0 or 1 (per the example in OP).
If this isn't true (and the Cats could be any range of values), change the formula per [chris neilsen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445425/chris-neilsen) suggestion (per comments):

```
=IF(OR(B1<>B2,&C1<>&C2),D2,SUM(E1,D2))
```

**Catering for Previous Same-State Categories**:
Both the original formula and the alternate above assume:
Should Cat A & Cat B states change, but subsequently return a 'previous same-state', the running total should still start afresh (i.e. don't 'carry forward' from 'previous same-states').

If one wanted the running balance to include the balance of previous same-states for Cat A & Cat B, use solution suggested by [Apostolos55](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683034/apostolos55) (below)

```
=SUMIFS($D$1:D2,$B$1:B2,B2,$C$1:C2,C2)
```

Comment: FYI the `B1&C1<>B2&C2` is a little vulnerable.  eg what if the data changes from `1, 11` to `11, 1`.  Might be better to use `OR(B1<>B2, C1<>C2)` (FWIW, in my opinion, once fixed, this is the best method)

Comment: @chris neilsen: Fair point. I assumed (and still assume), the specs are 'complete-for-purpose' (i.e. A and B are only ever 0 or 1). Still, your comment is helpful (so I marked it up). :)

Comment: It's your answer, leave it or change it as you see fit.  I just think 1) the OP should and probably has posted just a minimal example, not the real data. There's nothing in the Q to suggest that the real data is or isn't just 0/1. 2) the answer should be usefull for future readers too.  Posting an answer with that kind of vulnerability without mentioning its existance or stating your assumptions is simply laying a trap for the unwary 3) there is no down side to using the OR construct that I can see 4) I'm just trying to make your already good answer better.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is a minor adjustment to the cumulative count:

```
=Sumifs($D$2:D2,$B$2:B2,B2,$C$2:C2,C2)
```

Put in Current Count and it is done. Drag/drop OR Autocomplete down as needed

Now it takes into account only above/previous than the current...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but you can add a few columns:

- consecutive numbers from 2 to end of your data (say this is in Column G).
- references to every 10th cell (e.g. G2, G12) for every cell in that cluster. (say this is in Column H)
- you can fill in the first few rows for these two columns and then drag it down.
- a reference to the count column ('D') in a single cell (say I1).

You can then use `CONCATENATE` and `INDIRECT` inside `SUM`:

Cumulative Count:
`SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE($I$2,H2)):D2)`
and drag this down.